# which-azure-spring-boot-sample-active-directory-example-to-use-to-validate-acces-from resource server to server and vice versa calling

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, azure-active-directory

I have a frontend application in angular and backend in java language.
Goal:

1. to secure angular to spring boot application(A) with spring boot security and azure ad.
2. to secure above spring boot application(A)server api which will call other spring boot application(B) i.e. server to server resource security.
3. And spring boot application (B) calling spring boot application (A) with spring security.

Above project is a multimodule project.

Comment: What is your concrete question? What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck? (And: What is your question title supposed to mean?)

Comment: want an example of azure ad with spring security for securing server to server api calling and verification of the token

Comment: There still is no question. And my other points where also not answered.

Comment: Hi @user4886675, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 1):

•   Please follow the below documentation link which describes the **features and core scenarios of the Spring Boot application for Azure Active Directory (Azure AD)**. It explains in detail how to connect your spring boot application to an Azure AD tenant and protect your resource server with Azure AD. It uses the **OAuth 2.0 protocol to protect web applications and resource servers**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/spring-boot-starter-for-azure-active-directory-developer-guide

Do take into consideration that the above steps mentioned in the documentation uses **OAuth 2.0 authorization code grant flow for enabling a user to sign in with Microsoft account**.

•   And you will have to **develop and build your own spring boot java application to integrate Azure AD authentication along with resource protection in it**. The above documentation will help you `configure the accessibility of resource servers from a web application as well as protect that resource server/API or access other resource servers from a resource server. Thus, this satisfies all your requirements promptly if you follow it. Also, please do take into consideration that you will have to have all the prerequisites in place like a supported Java Development Kit version 8, Apache Maven version 3 or later and a spring boot application already registered with Azure AD`. Do refer to the link below for starter springboot Java application linked with Azure AD: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory***